# NavigationDrawer с кнопками

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, android-button

Мне нужно сделать NavigationDrawer, у которого фон будет являться картинкой, и в нём будет несколько кнопок, которые я могу расставлять как угодно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я надеюсь вы знаете как вообще делается сам `Navigation Drawer`, потому-что я не буду приводить схему создания этого виджета (если все-таки вы не знаете как это сделать, то напишите в комментариях и я дополню ответ). Итак чтобы установить свой фон в менюшке, вот способ:

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
(...)
mDrawerLayout.setBackgroundResource(int);
```

где в `setBackgroundResource` вы выставляете нужную вам картинку которую вам нужно будет закинуть в папку `drawable`. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092687/set-background-color-of-navigation-drawer) ссылка на интересующий вас вопрос.

Дальше чтобы разместить кнопки в вашем меню, вам вероятнее всего придется создать свой кастомный список, в основе которого будет только кнопка. А дальше вы делаете выбор пункта меню по стандарту.

Для изменения стандартного списка вам нужно файлик - `activity_message_center_drawer.xml`. Там вы можете поменять каждый пункт вашего списка меню, изменить иконки пунктов меню, или вообще забрать надписи и просто оставить ярлыки.

Надеюсь хоть чем-то помог в решении вашей проблемы, если что-то будет непонятно, спрашивайте и не стесняйтесь. Удачи :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83402/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-goroshko-navigationdrawer--).